# How can I redirect user to 404 page when database fail or when I want disconnect db permanently?

Tags: php, mysql

I want disconnect **one of** my databases as **permanently** and for connection to **this db** I use these codes:

```
$conn = mysql_pconnect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to database,please refresh your page.'); 
mysql_select_db($dbname);
```

Please let me know how can I do it best for this scenario (disconnecting db permanently) and when user comes from search engines redirect it to 404 page.

Comment: You can put `http_response_code(404);exit;` at the top of the page or use htaccess to redirect permanently. Your question is still not very clear to me. What do you mean one of your databases?

Comment: are you in php 5 or 7 ?

Comment: So are you retiring the whole PHP application at the same time then?

Comment: i use php5 for our site.we have 2 database in our website and want that disconnect one of them permanently .

Comment: Ok but a database is not directly accessible through a http request, so are you saying you have certain pages on your site which use that database alone, and you want all those pages to return a 404 if someone visits them?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to redirect the user to another page 404 on using the code bellow:

```
mysql_pconnect("localhost","root","","db_name")or die(header('Location: URL/404.php'));
```

Comment: I use mysql and not mysqli can i use your code for mysql?

Comment: Thanks it is ok .

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `die()` function in PHP to do this like so.

```
mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_name")or die(require("404.php"));
```

That will attempt to connect to your database and if it fails will require another file, you could also create a function that redirects users and stick that inside the `die()` function and simply redirect them to another page, either way that's how you would send users away upon an error with the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot close persistent mysql connection, which is what you have in your connection script (`mysql_pconnect`). At least you can't close it from PHP. Only way is to restart the mysql server. You need something like this from cmd:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Now after having restarted mysql, your persistent connection will be disconnected. If your goal is to disconnect it permanently, now you just need to make sure your connection script never runs again.

About the 404 redirection, you could use this at the top of your script:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

If you wish to send the user to a custom 404 page, you can use:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
include_once("404.html");
exit();
```

*note: with mysqli, if you are using PHP 7, there seems to be a way to clean persistent connection from PHP, see:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php

Comment: I use php 5 and at this time i cannot change mysql version.

Comment: can you restart mysql service ?

Comment: What is your mean for restart of mysql and what for?

Comment: Because you're connection code uses 'mysql_pconnect', the connection to your db will always stay open, unless you restart the mysql service on the server, or of course you could also reboot the server.  So basically, i’m just saying this is the only way you can disconnect your database for real.

Comment: With other answers, you will prevent users from querying the DB, but there will still be an active connection to your DB existing on the server. Check out https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php